# How to find footnote location in a paragraph in Microsoft Word using C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, footnotes, paragraphs

Currently I retrieve footnote text in a paragraph using

```
     foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph para in doc.Paragraphs)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range range = para.Range.Duplicate;

            string x = "";
            for (int i = 1; i <= para.Range.Footnotes.Count; i++)
            {
                x = para.Range.Footnotes[i].Range.Text;
             }
        }
```

But the text "x" I want to append next to footnote script in the paragraph for processing. I would like to know if there is anyway to navigate using location or split the paragraph using any delimiter for footnote marker so that I can recreate the text with body and footnote text appended to it.

Answer (score 0):

Best option, in my opinion, is to use `.Find property` of `Range object`. You will need to search for **`^f`** which represent footnote mark (within range).

First, I show you the code in VBA (which language I know much better):

```
para.Range.Select
Selection.Find.Execute "^f"
//'the code below will insert footnote text after your footnote mark
Selection.InsertAfter " " & Selection.Footnotes(1).Range.Text
```

I think in C# it will look as follows (or similar, not tested):

```
para.Range.Select;
Selection.Find.Execute("^f", ref Type.Missing, ref Type.Missing, ref Type.Missing, ref Type.Missing,
                             ref Type.Missing, ref Type.Missing, ref Type.Missing, ref Type.Missing,
                             ref Type.Missing, ref Type.Missing, ref Type.Missing, ref Type.Missing,
                             ref Type.Missing, ref Type.Missing);

Selection.InsertAfter(string.Format(" {0}", Selection.Footnotes[1].Range.Text));
```